# Como usar uma variavel cont p/ criar um array de names em input's?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um botão onde eu posso adicionar campos ao meu form, e preciso que cada novo campo tenha um name diferente, pensei em usar name = "produtos[]", e assim criar um array e usar um foreach no back, por exemplo. Podem me ajudar com essa concatenação? Já tentei algumas vezes e não consegui.

Essa é a função responsável por clonar os campos. a ideia era fazer name="produtos[cont]" e nos outros também, como fazer? Sei que dessa forma, sempre que eu chamar a função, o valor de cont voltará a ser 1, sugestões de como manter cont constante e de como zera-lo após enviar o formulário, por favor.

```
     $(function () {
      var srcDiv = $('#dinamicDiv');
      var cont = 1;
      $(document).on('click', '#addInput', function(){
          $('<p>'+
              '<label for="Produto" id="Produto" class="col-form-label">Nome do produto: </label>' +
              '<button id="removeInput" class="btn-danger btn-add">Remover produto</button>' +
              '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="produtos[]">' +
              '<label for="Preço" id="Preço" class="col-form-label">Preço do produto:</label>' +
              '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="preços[]">' +
             '</p>').appendTo(srcDiv);
          cont ++;
          return false;
      });
```

Comment: Coloquei no JsFiddle pra ficar melhor de entender: https://jsfiddle.net/Jaozim/5xj0tbrp/3/

Comment: Zerar contador isso se faz sozinho pelo próprio código caso você não o guarde em um Cookie por exemplo, e quanto a soma da sua var cont, você deve usar assim: cont = cont++;

Answer (score 0):

Não há a necessidade de declarar a posição do array no elemento, a menos que você queira que ele ocupe uma posição específica.

No seguinte exemplo, no seu backend você receberá o array ["foo", "bar", "baz"]:

```
<form>
    <input name="inp[]" value="foo">
    <input name="inp[]" value="bar">
    <input name="inp[]" value="baz">
</form>
```

Agora se você quiser declarar a posição manualmente, basta ter o contador iniciado fora do escopo do seu event listener. De fato você já está fazendo isso, só precisa concatenar o cont no HTML, e zera-lo depois que enviar seu form.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Eu sei que só preciso concatenar, essa é a questão, como faze-lo...?